# Iterate over all letters and numbers in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I am working on something where I need to create a set of folders for each letter and number. Currently, I am doing this:

```
for x in {0..9}
do
  mkdir -p /tmp/${x}
done
for x in {a..z}
do
  mkdir -p /tmp/${x}
done
```

Is there a way to make this statement more compact and include all numbers and letters in one `do` statement?

Further, out of curiosity, is there a way to do this for symbols?

Comment: `{0..9} {a..z}`

Comment: So `for x in {0..9} {a..z} ` for the first line?

Comment: `Further, out of curiosity, is there a way to do this for symbols` What do you define as "symbols"?

Comment: `-p` option is overkill here since `/tmp` exists.

Comment: @andlrc Any character that can comprise a filename that is not alphanumeric ~!@#$%^&_-+= etc.

Comment: @CinderBiscuits That includes interesting things like control characters (such as backspace), tabs, newlines, the `<beep>` sound, chinese characters, emoji, ...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Understood, this was an example. In the script I am writing it is necessary and there is a bit more substance to what is being done. For simplicity's sake I just used one command, but it's true that `-p` could be omitted.

Comment: Just to clarify, @melpomene's suggestion works without a for loop: `mkdir -p /tmp/{0..9} /tmp/{a..z}`

Comment: @BenjaminW. One can also use: `... /tmp/{{0..9},{a..z}}`

Comment: @andlrc Ah, I forgot about that. Even better.

Comment: *Everything* other than `/` and `NUL` are valid characters for a file name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put both expressions together in the `for` loop:

```
for x in {0..9} {a..z}; do
    mkdir -p "/tmp/${x}"
done
```

You can also do that in a single `mkdir` command:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/{{0..9},{a..z}}
```